# Do morph cards suffer summoning sickness

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When you have the card face down then you morph the card to face up, does it suffer summoning sickness? My friend has lots of them in his deck and I'm not too sure and would like to know whether they suffer from summoning sickness the turn they are morphed.

Answer (score 8):

Playing creatures face down and turning them face up (commonly called morphing/unmorphing) has no effect on them having summoning sickness. Unless they have haste, they have summoning sickness until they've been in play since the beginning of your most recent turn, whether they've been turned face up or not.

For example, if you play a creature face down then immediately turn it face up, it still has summoning sickness until your next turn. Similarly, if you play a creature face down, wait til it no longer has summoning sickness, and then turn it face up, it still doesn't have summoning sickness.

---

Morph does have a lot of interesting rules associated with it, but a morphed creature is still a creature. Morph means:

> You may cast this card as a 2/2 face-down creature with no text, no name, no subtypes, and no mana cost by paying {3} rather than paying its mana cost.

There's nothing in there about having haste, so like all creatures, it has summoning sickness. (It can't attack, and its activated abilities with a tap or untap symbol in their costs can't be activated unless it's been under your control since the beginning of your most recent turn.)

Similarly, turning it face up has its share of rules, but all it really does is turn the creature face up:

> [pay the cost] ... turn the permanent face up. ... The morph effect on it ends, and it regains its normal characteristics.

It's still the same creature it was before, so if it already had summoning sickness, it still does, and if it didn't have summoning sickness, it still doesn't.

Comment: How does the other player know that you are not cheating by using a random card as a 2/2 facedown morph?

Comment: If a morphed creature would switch zones, or play has finished, it must be revealed - see rule 707.9.

Comment: @Pacerier Best to ask things like that as new questions so everyone can benefit and you can get full answers!

Comment: I'd DV if I could. You spend 90% of your answer making it sound like the exact opposite of the conclusion (and correct answer).

Comment: @RubberDuck can you explain further? I don't see anything in the answer that contradicts the conclusion, and it all seems accurate to me.

Comment: @murgatroid99 the majority of the questions refers to how they will have "summoning sickness", but in reality they follow the same rules. Yes, the conclusion is correct, but the poor wording here can lead to even more confusion. I wouldn't concern myself about it, but for some reason it's the most upvoted answer atm.

Comment: So, there's two parts of the answer. The first part is talking about face-down creatures cast with the morph ability, which have summoning sickness just like any other creature (as the paragraph after the first rules quote says). The second part is talking about turning those creatures face up, which doesn't change summoning sickness (as the last paragraph says).

Comment: @RubberDuck I tried to make it even more explicit. I think you're focusing overly much on answering the question exactly the way the OP phrased it, as a yes or no question, while my answer is speaking more broadly about when the creature does and doesn't have summoning sickness (and why).

Comment: In your answer, I would use "play face down" and "turn face up" instead of "morph" and "unmorph". If you look closely at the question, you'll notice that the OP thinks "morph" means "turn face up", which is exactly the opposite of how you have used the same term in your answer. Also (and this is *really* getting picky), when 90% of the sentences in your answer have three or four clauses broken up with commas, it is hard to read. Try to vary your sentence structure (short and to the point, lengthy explanation, short again, long again, etc.).

Comment: @Rainbolt Changed the face up/face down. As for the rest, as you say, it's pretty picky - and it's more a matter of personal style than anything else. If sentence length is forced to vary when things actually require explanation, it can easily make things harder to read. If there's something specific you think needs clarifying I'm happy to reword, though.

Comment: @TheForestAndTheTrees, Ic, is that the reason why there are so many names on [the Suspended List](http://magic.wizards.com/en/content/suspended-dci-memberships)?

Comment: @Pacerier At this point, you're asking unrelated questions in the comments. Please post your question as an actual question or take it to chat.

Answer (score 4):

Let's recollect the summoning sickness rule:

> **302.6.** A creature’s activated ability with the tap symbol or the untap symbol in its activation cost can’t be activated unless the creature has been under its controller’s control continuously since his or her most recent turn began. A creature can’t attack unless it has been under its controller’s control continuously since his or her most recent turn began. This rule is informally called the “summoning sickness” rule.

A creature with morph fully obeys this rule. If you cast a creature and then morph it on the same turn - it will suffer from summoning sickness. If you morph it during next turns and you didn't lose control of it - it won't suffer from summoning sickness and will be able to attack or use "tap" activated abilities.

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't have "summoning sickness" unless it already had it.

Turning the card face up ("morphing") just changes its characteristics, just like [Giant Growth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Giant%20Growth) does. Turning the card face up doesn't give or take away "summoning sickness" any more than Giant Growth does.

If you haven't controlled the card since the beginning of your turn, it has summoning sickness. If it's a creature, it can't attack, and you can't use it's {T} or {Q} abilities.

> 302.6. A creature’s activated ability with the tap symbol or the untap symbol in its activation cost can’t be activated unless the creature has been under its controller’s control continuously since his or her most recent turn began. A creature can’t attack unless it has been under its controller’s control continuously since his or her most recent turn began. This rule is informally called the “summoning sickness” rule.

Answer (score 1):

Morphing doesn't actually change the state of summoning sickness at all. Summoning sickness is more a property **of the card,** and it affects cards that have Creature type.

So, if the card has summoning sickness while it's face-down, it'll still have summoning sickness when it's turned face up. If it doesn't have summoning sickness, turning it face-up won't re-give it summoning sickness: it's in the clear, it can attack and pay tap costs immediately, etc.

The lore behind morphing has always had the notion of a creature leaping out from disguise when it was turned face up. In the Onslaught block, [morph creatures came from a spider-shaped shell](https://web.archive.org/web/20150922082153/http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtgcom/arcana/1191). In Tarkir, morph takes on the flavour of being [obscured by dragon magic](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/mm/khan-do-attitude-part-2-2014-09-08):

> In the story, morph is descended from a draconic magic. The humans (and humanoid creatures) of Tarkir managed to take the draconic magic and warp it to their own means. The key to the magic is that it hides the identity of the creature using it, making it harder to fight against, as you are forced to fight blindly without any knowledge of your foe.

So you're not summoning a new creature out of Morph that would obtain summoning sickness; the creature casts its disguise aside fully alert.